# how to hide incoming text to password?

Tags: html, angular

im working on a angular project in a certain field im getting password and displaying it on front end i want to hide that text into password field eg "****" like this can anyone help me with the code please ?

- details.component.html

  ```
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12" >
          <div class="ui-g-5 ui-md-5 ui-md-nopad ui-g-nopad">Password</div> 
          <div class="ui-g-1 ui-md-1 ui-md-nopad ui-g-nopad">:</div>
          <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-6 ui-md-nopad ui-g-nopad"  style="text-transform:none"> 
          {{agentdata?.password?agentdata?.password:"Notavailable"}}</div>
        </div>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use an `input` element for hiding password.

```
<input type="password" value="Password">
```

Provide your password text to the `value` attribute of `input` element.

Comment: thank you so much , just a issue it is creating a input box i dont want input box/or to change value i just want to display it in password type

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want input box, you can do it with pipe.

**mask-value.pipe.ts:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'maskValue'
})
export class MaskValuePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): any {
    if (value == null || value.length === 0) {
      return value;
    }

    return '*'.repeat(value.length);
  }

}
```

**html**

```
<div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-6 ui-md-nopad ui-g-nopad"  style="text-transform:none"> 
{{agentdata?.password?agentdata?.password | maskValue }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- first it is not a good thing to fetch a password from server to front-end because anyone can know it if you take a look to the network request tab
- even if you are encoding it if you are decoding it on front-end it is still vulnerable
- Because of this as your requirement you can return password to available or not available from the back-end and return it to frontend

or you can pass a boolean and valid it on front-end as below,

```
 {{agentdata?.password?agentdata?.password === true? '******' :"Notavailable"}}
```

Comment: thank you for the advice and answer but after replacing code im not able to open that tab .May I know any alternate way to solve this please ?

Comment: did you change you backend code to send a value true? what is the error are you getting?
try changing it to {{agentdata?.password?agentdata?.password? '******' :"Notavailable"}}

we cannot give a proper answer if your not providing the response for not having password?

Comment: solved the issue with type and value metho  ,thank you for the help though